# Verify inequality $k\cos(\frac{1}{x})>\cos(\frac{1}{kx})$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Verify that the following inequality .

$$k\cos(\frac{1}{x})>\cos(\frac{1}{kx})$$

holds for $k>1$ and $x>2$.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: This can be rewritten as $k\cos(y)>\cos(y/k)$ for $k>1$ and $y<\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Or $\cos(y)>\beta\cos(\beta y)$ for $0<y<\frac{1}{2}$ and $0<\beta<1.$

Comment: I definitely agree for the suggested equivalent expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) =  k\cos\frac{1}{x}-\cos\frac{1}{kx}$. Then, examine
$$f'(x) = \frac1{kx^2}\left( k^2\sin \frac1x -\sin\frac1{kx}\right)>0$$

where the inequality is due to $x>2$ and $k>1$. Then,

$$f(x) > f(2) = k\cos\frac12 -\cos\frac1{2k}
=\int_1^k \left(\cos\frac12-\frac1{2t^2}\sin\frac1{2t}\right)dt\tag 1$$

Given that $t\ge1$, we have $\frac1{2t^2}\sin\frac1{2t} < \frac1{2}\sin\frac1{2}$, which leads to

$$\cos\frac12-\frac1{2t^2}\sin\frac1{2t}> \cos\frac12-\frac1{2}\sin\frac1{2}>0$$

and the inequality (1) becomes $f(x) >f(2) >  0$. Thus,

$$k\cos\frac{1}{x}>\cos\frac{1}{kx}$$

Comment: Dear Quanto, I am completely satisfied for the solution you suggested. I think you mean if $t>1$, then $\frac1{2t^2}\sin\frac1{2t} < \frac1{2}\sin\frac1{2}$ or maybe if $t\geq{1}$, then $\frac1{2t^2}\sin\frac1{2t} \leq \frac1{2}\sin\frac1{2}$. Thank you so much again for the excellent approach and explanation.

Comment: @user101496 -You're quite welcome. Appreciate careful reading.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: You might make a change of variables $1/x = t \text{ and } 0 < t < 1/2$.

$$k\cos(t) > \cos\left(\frac{t}{k}\right)$$

You can probably finish here by doing a low level polynomial approximation or Taylor series investigation.

Comment: Dear Mathreadler, thank you so much for your suggestion, that might seems in somehow better form.